# Iterate all email items in a specific Outlook folder

Tags: vba, outlook

How can I in an Outlook VBA macro iterate all email items in a specific Outlook folder (in this case the folder belongs not to my personal inbux but is a sub-folder to the inbox of a shared mailbox.

Something like this but I've never done an Outlook macro...

```
For each email item in mailboxX.inbox.mySubfolder.items
// do this
next item
```

I tried this but the inbox subfolder is not found...

```
Private Sub Application_Startup()

Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim objFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Set objNS = GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set objFolder = objNS.Folders("myGroupMailbox")
Set objFolder = objFolder.Folders("Inbox\mySubFolder1\mySubFolder2")

  On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
  Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem

For Each Item In objFolder.Items

  If TypeName(Item) = "MailItem" Then

    Set Msg = Item
    If new_msg.Subject Like "*myString*" Then
        strBody = myItem.Body
        Dim filePath As String
        filePath = "C:\myFolder\test.txt"
        Open filePath For Output As #2
        Write #2, strBody
        Close #2

    End If

  End If

ProgramExit:
  Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
  MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
  Resume ProgramExit

Next Item

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the bit you are struggling with? Is it "how to select the right subfolder"?

Comment: yes, but I've never done an Outlook macro and only want to iterate this folder with some simple actions but the examples I've found seem pretty complicated. Is there anything else I need to add to run the loop?

Comment: Do you get an error message or does it just not find something that you know is there? Either way I think you should move the `next item` line to before the `ProgramExit` label, at present you will exit the sub before reaching it.

Answer (score 4):

In my case the following worked:

```
Sub ListMailsInFolder()

    Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim objFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder

    Set objNS = GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set objFolder = objNS.Folders.GetFirst ' folders of your current account
    Set objFolder = objFolder.Folders("Foldername").Folders("Subfoldername")

    For Each Item In objFolder.Items
        If TypeName(Item) = "MailItem" Then
            ' ... do stuff here ...
            Debug.Print Item.ConversationTopic
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Likewise, you can as well iterate through calender items:

```
Private Sub ListCalendarItems()
        Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
        Set olNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

        Set olRecItems = olNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderTasks)
        strFilter = "[DueDate] > '1/15/2009'"
        Set olFilterRecItems = olRecItems.Items.Restrict(strFilter)
        For Each Item In olFilterRecItems
        If TypeName(Item) = "TaskItem" Then
            Debug.Print Item.ConversationTopic
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

**Note** that this example is using filtering and also `.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderTasks)` to get the builtin folder for calendar items. If you want to access the inbox, for example, use `olFolderInbox`.

Answer (score 3):

The format is:

```
Set objFolder = objFolder.Folders("Inbox").Folders("mySubFolder1").Folders("mySubFolder2")
```

As advised in a comment "move the next item line to before the ProgramExit label"

Answer (score 3):

```
Sub TheSub()

Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim fldrImAfter As Outlook.Folder
Dim Message As Outlook.MailItem

    'This gets a handle on your mailbox
    Set objNS = GetNamespace("MAPI")

    'Calls fldrGetFolder function to return desired folder object
    Set fldrImAfter = fldrGetFolder("Folder Name Here", objNS.Folders)

    For Each Message In fldrImAfter.Items
        MsgBox Message.Subject
    Next

End Sub
```

Recursive function to loop over all folders until the specified folder name is found....

```
Function fldrGetFolder( _
                    strFolderName As String _
                    , objParentFolderCollection As Outlook.Folders _
                    ) As Outlook.Folder

Dim fldrSubFolder As Outlook.Folder

    For Each fldrGetFolder In objParentFolderCollection

        'MsgBox fldrGetFolder.Name

        If fldrGetFolder.Name = strFolderName Then
            Exit For
        End If

        If fldrGetFolder.Folders.Count > 0 Then
            Set fldrSubFolder = fldrGetFolder(strFolderName, 
fldrGetFolder.Folders)
            If Not fldrSubFolder Is Nothing Then
                Set fldrGetFolder = fldrSubFolder
                Exit For
            End If
        End If

    Next

End Function
```