# Resend emails stuck in Outbox

Tags: vba, outlook

I found a script online to resend emails stuck in the Outbox in Outlook 365. It requires that I select the emails.

I have two accounts, including a Microsoft Exchange account. Is there any way to modify this macro so that when I send an email in the Microsoft Exchange account, all emails which may be stuck in the Outbox, are automatically selected and the below macro is run?

```vb
Sub BatchResendEmails()
    Dim objSelection As Outlook.Selection
    Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim objInspector As Outlook.Inspector
    Dim objResendMail As Outlook.MailItem

    Set objSelection = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
 
    If Not (objSelection Is Nothing) Then
        On Error Resume Next
        For Each objMail In objSelection
            objMail.Display
            Set objInspector = myItem.GetInspector
 
            'Resend message
            objInspector.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("ResendThisMessage")
  
            Set objResendMail = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
 
            'You can change the email details as per your needs
            With objResendMail
                .Subject = objMail.Subject
                .Send
            End With
 
            objMail.Close olDiscard
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head:

```
    Sub BatchResendEmails()
    Dim objFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim objInspector As Outlook.Inspector
    Dim objResendMail As Outlook.MailItem

    Set objFolder = Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderOutbox)
 
       On Error Resume Next
       For Each objMail In objFolder.Items
           objMail.Display
           Set objInspector = myItem.GetInspector
 
           'Resend message
           objInspector.CommandBars.ExecuteMso ("ResendThisMessage")
  
           Set objResendMail = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
 
           'You can change the email details as per your needs
           With objResendMail
               .Subject = objMail.Subject
               .Send
           End With
 
           objMail.Close olDiscard
       Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, but it comes back with a Run Time error '438"          Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: See the change above

Comment: Thanks.  It works when I run the script manually.  But is there a way for this script to automatically run whenever I send an email in the Exchange account?

Comment: To be more specific, I want this script to run automatically whenever I click the Send button in the Exchange account.  Thanks.

Comment: Alternatively, I would like to schedule the script to run periodically (i.e. every 5 minutes) using Windows Task Scheduler or running a batch file.  I appreciate your assistance.

Comment: There is nothing out of the box that will let you run it automatically.

Comment: OK, then how can I schedule this script to run every 5 minutes?  I have read about using task scheduler and creating a vbs or bat file, but not sure how to do that since this is VBA code.

Comment: That's what I meant- automatically means "on a timer".
Task scheduler does not work too well with Outlook scripts. You can create a COM addin, then you can run that code (or similar) whenever your want.

Answer (score 0):

To remove the manual selection of the folder set a reference to the folder https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getdefaultfolder.

To remove the manual selection of items [Iterate all email items in a specific Outlook folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21556389/iterate-all-email-items-in-a-specific-outlook-folder/45575389).
You may need a reverse loop when decreasing the number of items in the outbox [For Each loop: Some items get skipped when looping through Outlook mailbox to delete items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10725068/for-each-loop-some-items-get-skipped-when-looping-through-outlook-mailbox-to-de).

To run code periodically [Outlook VBA - Run a code every half an hour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12257985/outlook-vba-run-a-code-every-half-an-hour).